# How do I exclude the first character if its 0 from a string in python (in a randomly generated string)

Tags: python, random, generator

So I'm new to this site, and I'm trying to solve something in my code. I'm trying to make a lightshot screenshot scraper in python, but I've found out any code that starts with 0 will redirect to the home page, and would like to avoid that.
My current code and an example output:

```
import string
import random
def main():
  def gen(x):
    N = 6
    r = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k = N))
    if not string.startswith("0"):
      print("https://prnt.sc/" + str(r) + ' ' + f"{i}")
  x = int(input("How many links would you like to generate? please input a number."))
  for i in range(x):
    gen(x)
  q = input("Would you like to generate more? (say 'y' or 'n'.)")
  if q == "y":
    main()
  else:
   quit()
main()
```

```
>>>How many links would you like to input? Please put a number.3
>>>https://prnt.sc/(insert random string here, not here because there are scams on lightshot)
>>>https://prnt.sc/(random string)
>>>https://prnt.sc/(random string)
```

I've tried looking it up and asking a friend, and i am either wayyy too tired or just don't know what to do. prob both, as i am pretty new to python. Any help I could receive here?

Comment: I think you might want to include what the exact problem is

Comment: if not string[0] == 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from your `string.startswith("0")`

The string module doesn't have that method.

You need to call the startswith() method on a string object.

From your code I will assume that you want to use startswith on the random string `r`

Here is the fixed code that runs:

```
import random
import string


def main():
    def gen(x):
        N = 6
        r = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=N))
        if not r.startswith("0"):
            print("https://prnt.sc/" + str(r) + ' ' + f"{i}")

    x = int(input("How many links would you like to generate? please input a number."))
    for i in range(x):
        gen(x)
    q = input("Would you like to generate more? (say 'y' or 'n'.)")
    if q == "y":
        main()
    else:
        quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This fixed it, thanks! But I forgot to mention I didn't mean to leave 'string.startswith("0")' in the code, must've forgot to remove it before posting, but you fixed it! You're a legend, thanks

Comment: Glad to have helped. Don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted if it solved your case.

Answer (score 0):

also you are using `string.startswith` did you mean `r` since that is the string you are generating?

```
import string
import random
def main():
  def gen(x):
    N = 6
    r = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k = N))
    if not r.startswith("0"):
      print("https://prnt.sc/" + str(r) + ' ' + f"{i}")
  x = int(input("How many links would you like to generate? please input a number."))
  for i in range(x):
    gen(x)
  q = input("Would you like to generate more? (say 'y' or 'n'.)")
  if q == "y":
    main()
  else:
   quit()
main()
```

Alternatively, if you meant you don't want the first string (of the number generated to print) you could alter your for loop.

```
 for i in range(1,x):
    gen(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, for both things, the number on the side is just so I can browse through them easier but that does help a tiny bit. Maybe I should resume learning python.. lol.

Comment: glad to help, best of luck on your coding journey!